# delete entire row if we have specific value or text and also delete 7 below rows

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I want to delete entire row if we have specific value or text and also delete 7 below rows from that value or text. I have this code. It works but it will only delete that specific row. How can I delete below 7 entire rows.

```
 Sub sbDelete_Rows_Based_On_Criteria()
 Dim lRow As Long 
 Dim iCntr As Long 
 lRow = 4395
 For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1 
   If Cells(iCntr, 1) = “HeaderName” Then 
     Rows(iCntr).EntireRow.Delete 
   End If 
 Next 
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to delete the row with "HeaderName" *and* the 7 rows below it:

```
Sub sbDelete_Rows_Based_On_Criteria()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long

    lRow = 4395
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 1) = "HeaderName" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Resize(8).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

if you want to keep the row with "HeaderName" and delete the 7 rows below it:

```
Sub sbDelete_Rows_Based_On_Criteria2()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long

    lRow = 4395
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 1) = "HeaderName" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Offset(1).Resize(7).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Find option to get the cell with what you are looking for.

```
Columns("A:A").Find(What:="bla").Resize(7).EntireRow.Delete
```